# How to create awk regex to match only one "space" between two words?

Tags: regex, awk, gawk

I have a sentence of form `2016-23-12 90-34-23` want to create an `awk` script to match it.

a.awk

```
$1 ~ /^[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}[[:space:]][[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}/{
  ts = $1 " " $2
  print
}
```

Run using:

```
awk -f a.awk --posix

2016-23-12 90-34-23
```

Output:

Nothing

Comment: What do you want to archive with the term at the end: { ts = $1 " " $2 print }?

Answer (score 1):

I *assume* your intention is match the *whole string*, in which `$1` is incorrect, use it as `$0`

The problem you are seeing is `Awk` [dynamic regular-expressions](https://w3-o.cs.hm.edu/~ruckert/compiler/regexp.html#Computed-Regexps) like the one you used don't need the `$0 ~ /regex/` type match, the `//` is not needed here, just do as with your script being,

```
dynamicRegex = "[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}[[:space:]][[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}"

$0 ~ dynamicRegex {
    print "match success"
}
```

and now running the script as

```
echo "2016-23-12 90-34-23"| awk -f a.awk --posix
2016-23-12 90-34-23
match success
```

Quoting from the page,

> [..]The righthand side of a `~` or `!~` operator need not be a regexp constant (i.e., a string of characters between slashes). It may be any expression. The expression is evaluated and converted to a string if necessary; the contents of the string are used as the regexp. A regexp that is computed in this way is called a *dynamic regexp* [..]

Another way would be to use the normal Regular Expression syntax over the `POSIX` character classes as a *regexp constant* as below,

```
$0 ~ /^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$/ {
    print "match success"
}
```

Remember with the above regex, your script is not longer `POSIX` compatible and running with `--posix` won't work here, also the `\s` here is a `GNU Awk` specific construct. Running it as

```
echo "2016-23-12 90-34-23"| awk -f a.awk
match success
```

Now to print the line upon the match, upon success just do,

```
print $1 FS $2
```

after the earlier `print` command.

Comment: I want to use this regex for a log line of form "2016-12-03 12:10:34 INFO Some text" and just want to get the timestamp string for some comparison purpose.The above solution accepts all inputs for me like asb-wer-12 ,12-34-12,etc. means it is not filtering according to input regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$echo "2016-23-12 90-34-23"  | awk '{if($0 ~ /^[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}[[:space:]][[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}$/) {print $0}}'
2016-23-12 90-34-23

$echo "2016-23-121 190-34-23"  | awk '{if($0 ~ /^[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}[[:space:]][[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}$/) {print $0}}'
   ##### No result
```

Comment: It also matches the string, `echo "2016-23-121 190-34-23"`, which is not supposed to be matched, hence incorrect

Comment: Please refer my answer in detail, OP wants to use an `awk` script and not in command line and what you have used is _not_ a dynamic regexp which OP is looking for, just `$0 ~ regex` and not within conditionals.

Comment: @Inian - Thanks for your comment but I was under the impression to solve the regex issue not spoon feeding, If regex is working fine then we can use it as one liner, dynamic regex  or `awk` script.